# How to check a json object contains value?

Tags: javascript, json

My test code:

```
var x = {};
alert(x['a'] != 'undefined');
alert(x['a'] !== 'undefined');
```

Both of them alert: `true`. Why?

I don't declare `x['a']` before.

Comment: `undefined !== "undefined"`

Comment: How is JSON involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking if it equals the string "undefined".

Try `typeof x['a'] !== 'undefined'`

Answer (score 2):

Test if `x` contains property `a`:

```js
var x = {};
alert('a' in x);
```